# stored procedure isn't working in mysql on expressjs

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, express, stored-procedures

Trying to call a stored procedure I wrote in mysql on my express api. Here is the stored procedure.

```
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT DTime, ', 
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN TagName = ''', TagName, ''' THEN Value END) AS ', TagName)
                    )
                    FROM values01
                    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(TagName, @tags)
                    ),
                    ' FROM values01
                    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(TagName, @tags)
                    AND DTime BETWEEN ? AND ?
                    GROUP BY DTime
                    ORDER BY DTime');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @start_time, @end_time;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and here is the express code

```
  try {
    // Change to req.query in axios
    const { tags, startDate, endDate } = req.query;

    const params = [tags.join(","), startDate, endDate];
    const query = "call dustint_testDB.getDataFromTags(?, ?, ?)";

    pool.execute(query, params, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ response: result });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
```

The params look like  [ 'DF1,SD24,DF4', '2024-02-07 12:04:00', '2024-02-28 12:04:00' ] and I always get
'error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1"'
in the response.

Comment: Your code uses UDV `@tags` which is assigned with the value nowhere.. simply replace PREPARE/EXEC/DROP with `SELECT @sql, @tags;` and investigate...

Comment: *Here is the stored procedure.* Here is a part of it. You must provide complete code, from CREATE PROCEDURE till final END, inclusive.